# FireBase Analytics をUnityで導入

Tags: android, firebase, unity2d

Unityで作成しているスマホアプリにFireBase Analyticsを導入しようと思い、SDKをインポートし、google-service.jsonをプロジェクトに含めるところまで行いました。
それからLogEventを使ってボタンを押したことやゲームのクリア判定をロギングしようとしたのですが、なぜかユーザとして認識されないですし、LogEventを挟んでいるボタンは、イベントが実行されなくなってしまいました。

DebugViewを使ったりなど様々な記事を参考にしましたが、どうも決定的な解決策が見つかりませんでした。
この問題の解決策になりそうな情報をお持ちの方がいらっしゃいましたら、どうか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Comment: Unityでエラーログも出ていませんか？

Comment: 実機でテストを行なっているので、その状態のエラーログは分かりません。
しかし、Unityエディタ上でビルドした時などにエラーログは一切出ておりませんし、例外検出を行なっても例外は発生していないようでした。